# Access to MediaShield RAID utility

Tags: raid, bios, graphics-processing-unit

I'm using RAID-1 configuration on a PC which will be accessible by many people who are not very experienced with computers. So I want to restrict access to MediaShield RAID configuration utility which pops-up on every boot proposing to press F10 button.
Is there a way to hide that boot message or protect the utility with a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is to modify the string in the RAID portion of BIOS. It works okay.

Answer (score 0):

The MediaShield (RAID) BIOS is after all a firmware component which belongs more to the NVIDIA Chipset as to the actual Mainboard BIOS.  The firmware module is provided by NVIDIA and usually integrated into the BIOS Code as is. Modifications regarding password protection of the RAID Firmware would more or less fall into the responsability of NVIDIA.

I am not sure what happens if you set a BIOS Password in BIOS Setup, but I suppose that it will not restrict access to the MediaShield Firmware (because it is not really a functional part of the system BIOS, but of the RAID Controller integrated in the NVIDIA Chipset).

Quote

> Is there a way to disable that message
>   or set a password for the tool?

As far as I understand the functionality of the MediaShield BIOS, this would only be possible by modifying the NVIDIA RAID Firmware Module, which is something MSI is most probably not going to do.

Comment: I'm proceeding with the solution of replacing "press F10" message with zeros in MediaShield BIOS file and reflashing MB's BIOS with modified version.